# How could I read a dictionary that contains a function from a text file?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to read a dictionary from a text file. This dictionary seems like `{'key': [1, ord('@')]}`. I read about `eval()` and `literal_eval()`, but none of those two will work due to `ord()`.

I also tried `json.loads` and `json.dumps`, but no positive results.

Which other way could I use to do it?

Comment: How did you make the text file? You should be using `json.dump` if it's supposed to be later read by a json parser.

Comment: Well, `eval()` would do the job - it would also erase your hard drive, if someone with bad intentions towards you ever gained control of the text file.  Do you have any known limits on what the functions in the file are allowed to be?  If it's only `ord()` of string literals, you could easily replace them with their equivalent numeric values, then apply `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: What do you expect the contents of the dictionary to be after it's read in?

Comment: `eval` would work, something like `eval(file.read())` But why is this a text file to begin with? This is just python source code

Answer (score 1):

So Assuming you read the text file in with `open` as a string and not with `json.loads` you could do some simple regex searching for what is between the parenthesis of ord e.g ***`ord('@')`*** -> ***`@`***

This is a minimal solution that reads everything from the file as a single string then finds all instances of ord and places the integer representation in an output list called `ord_`. For testing this example `myfile.txt` was a text file with the following in it

**{"key": [1, "ord('@')"],**

**"key2": [1, "ord('K')"]}**

```py
import json
import re
with open(r"myfile.txt") as f:
    json_ = "".join([line.rstrip("\n") for line in f])

rgx = re.compile(r"ord\(([^\)]+)\)")
rgd = rgx.findall(json_)
ord_ = [ord(str_.replace(r"'", "")) for str_ in rgd]
```

Answer (score 0):

- `json.dump()` and `json.load()` will not work because `ord()` is not JSON Serializable (meaning that the function cannot be a JSON object.
- Yes, `eval` is really bad practice, I would never recommend it to anyone for any use.

The best way I can think of to solve this is to use conditions and an extra list.

```py
# data.json = {'key': [1, ['ord', '@']]}    # first one is function name, second is arg
with open("data.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
# data['key'][1][0] is "ord"
if data['key'][1][0] == "ord":
    res = ord(data['key'][1][1])
```